# Concrete for making concrete molds

Tags: concrete, cement

I am trying to make some concrete items such as trays, vases, bowls etc.
Can anyone please advise on recipes/ratios for this? I would like to make these in white, black and grey and want a smooth finish (lump free and non gritty)

Thanks,

James

Comment: This question might do better on the Arts and Crafts site.

Comment: Are you sure you want concrete (with gravel/stones in the mix) and not mortar (smooth cement/sand mix)?

Comment: Hi, thanks, it is a mortar from your description above. I'm fairly new to the terminology. Would you be able to help with ratios / recipes and brands to buy please?

Comment: I wouldn't try to make my own mix - just go to your nearest home improvement store and buy a bag of ready-mixed mortar. This gives you gray. Get a small bag of black oxide pigment for black (you may need to use quite a lot for a really deep black and will probably need to experiment a bit to get a shade you like). For white you'll need white cement mixed with white sand - 1:3 ratio should work fine. You could also use this to lighten the gray of you want to.